# Python3 different between external terminal and VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord.py

So I have recently tried to install discord.py in python to create a discord bot. I ran the install and everything was fine. I have a test Bot and can run it with no issue. But when i open up my code in Visual Studio Code the pylint shows an error at the import for discord. I have ran help("modules") in the integrated terminal and in an external terminal and they show different module lists. I did "which python3" on both terminals and they both point to the same python3 file. I am at a loss as to why they could be different module lists but point to the same location.

Comment: See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: See what is getting me is that I installed "numpy" just the other day for school and it worked fine but with discord its not.

Comment: Are you running in virtual environments?  Are you running Unix, Linux, or PC.

Comment: Linux, and no i am not.

Comment: What shows up in the terminal for `python3` will not necessarily match what environment you have selected in the extension. Check what is specified in your status bar to make sure it matches. You can also manually specify the path by setting your `"python.pythonPath"` setting or by running the `Select Interpreter` command.